# IntelliJ IDEA & Bitbucket plugin (replace with earlier commit)

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12 Community Edition and have installed the Bitbucket plugin. 
I can right click on a file and do: Git > Show History > then right-click a commit and say GET. This gets the file contents of that commit.. great!

But now i have deleted a whole folder and i want to get it back. So i do: right-click on the ROOT of my project and do the same: Git > Show in history > right click on one commit, but now GET is greyed out!

I simply would like to revert back to my old commit, which still holds that folder and its contents. I am fine with replacing my complete project with that old commit.

In Eclipse there was an option like: Replace with > commit. 
Is there something similar here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

-Click ALT-9 
-Click on Log tab 
-Right-click on a commit 
-Select Checkout revision (or Cherry pick to select what to checkout)